# Using template tag in ModelAdmin.readonly_fields method

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I use this pattern:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('address_report',)

    def address_report(self, instance):
        return format_html(...)
```

Source: [docs about readonly_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields)

Now I would like to use a custom templatetag in the Python method `address_report()`.

What is the best way to call it?

I tried to called my templatetag directly, but this just returns a dictionary, not html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll have to create a template from string. That way you can use any template tags or variables you want.

Example:

```
from django.template import Template, Context

def address_report(...):
    # create template
    t = Template("""
       {% load custom_tag_module %}
        <p>
            Hello, {{ name }}! <br>
            {% custom_tag %}
        </p>
        """)

    # create context
    c = Context({'name': 'World'})

    # render template, mark safe and return
    return mark_safe(t.render(c))
```